# Flutter how to get a Future<bool> to a normal bool type

Tags: android, ios, flutter, dart

Hi I'm trying to get a Future to be used as a normal boolean, how do I use this function as the determiner for a normal boolean without it giving me an incorrect type error?

```
Future<bool> checkIfOnAnyChats() async {
    FirebaseUser user = await _auth.currentUser();

    final QuerySnapshot result = await _firestore
        .collection('chats')
        .where('members', arrayContains: _username)
        .getDocuments();
    final List<DocumentSnapshot> documents = result.documents;

    if(documents.length > 0) {
      return Future<bool>.value(true);
    }else{
      return Future<bool>.value(false);
    }
  }
```

How do I apply it to a normal type boolean and not get this error? Thanks.
[image]

Answer (score 1):

you don't need to convert bool into future, as you are in async method it will return future only.

you can get that value in initstate, you can not get value outside any method.

```
bool _isInChat;

@override
void initState() {
  super.initState();
  CheckIfOnAnyChats().then((value){
     SetState((){
       _isInChat = value;
     });
  });
}
```

Comment: can you add where you are calling ? also check my answer

Comment: I want to basically return a Visibility widget and hide it if the person is not on the list and show if the person is on the list of the firestore database. Thanks.

Comment: @VirenVVarasadiya Can you please add some comments to your answr to make it more explanatory?